# Asset precompile error on Capistrano deploy for a couple refreshes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, capistrano, assets

There is an issue I have been struggling for quite some while now.

I have been deploying using Capistrano 3.
In my Capfile i use

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'sidekiq/capistrano'
require 'whenever/capistrano'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

And whenever I deploy, it throws me an EACCES permission denied error

[image]

so I managed to overcome this error using this piece of code

```
desc 'Fixing up cache permissions'
task :fix_assets_permission do
  on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do

    puts "chown -R root:root #{shared_path.join('tmp/cache')};"
    puts "chmod 666 -R #{shared_path.join('tmp/cache')};"

    execute "chown -R root:root #{shared_path.join('tmp/cache')};"
    execute "chmod 666 -R #{shared_path.join('tmp/cache')};"
  end
end
```

and putting it after assets precompiling like this

```
after 'deploy:compile_assets', 'deploy:fix_assets_permission'
```

and it worked just fine, however whenever I deploy, first couple of refreshes it still throws out exact same error and then works out just fine.

How can I possibly fix this issue so this error doesn't pops up every time i deploy project.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPD:** as user John pointed out, I should clear cache, and that indeed fixes the issue HOWEVER this error still pops up at the time of deploy, until it finishes assets precompiling and clears cache. Is there anything I could do to allow "zero downtime deploy" in this case.

I have modified my deploy.rb task like this

```
desc 'Clearing cache'
task :clear_cache do
  on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    within release_path do
      execute :rake, 'tmp:clear'
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:compile_assets', 'deploy:clear_cache'
```

Comment: Try clearing the tmp folder with `rake tmp:clear` and see if the problem goes away. Are you using Apache?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for taking time in replying. rake tmp:clear indeed fixes the issue, but in the context of Capistrano, there is still quite a little bit of downtime while assets are being precompiled, only once assets had been compiled, cache is cleared and this error goes away. Think you have any thoughts on how to make it a zero downtime deploy? I have updated question with more information.

Comment: Oh and I am using Passenger

Comment: For the cache clearing you probably don't need to do that on every deployment. I only suggested it because you had recently changed the permissions on the project's tmp/cache directory and may have had bad files in there.

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that will do zero downtime deployments with Capistrano. It's going to take some configuration. Passenger enterprise version has zero downtime ability, but I don't think that's free. If you want to roll your own check out http://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2014/03/08/zero-downtime-deployment-with-unicorn-and-capistrano/ and http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a much cleaner deploy tool such as [mina](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina). Its a far simpler tool that is far more reliable and faster because of the approach it uses.  In our setup Capistrano caused more problems than it solved.

Migrating our multi-stage deploy to mina took very little effort and we have never looked back. I can't fathom how many years Capistrano 3 has been in the wilderness to do what boils down to running a remote script.

Heres [an article constrasting mina and capistrano](https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/faster-web-application-deployments-using-mina-instead-of-capistrano).